# Change responseStatusCode when returning customer Exception object

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception, http-status-codes

I built a rest API using Spring Boot, that returns a custom ResponseEntity when an excpetion occurs using a class `xxEntity` that I created

```java
public class xxEntity<T> {
    private T body;
    private HttpStatus status;
    private int statusCode;
    private xxException error;

    public xxEntity(T body) {
        this.body = body;
        status = HttpStatus.OK;
        this.statusCode = status.value();
    }

    public xxEntity(HttpStatus status, xxException error) {
        this.status = status;
        this.statusCode = status.value();
        this.error = error;
    }
}
```

When there is an exception I return the entity as following:

```java
return new xxEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, new xxException(ex));
```

Where `ex` is a json containing the `String`french message, `String`english message and an `int`internal error code.

It returns a custom object with the following details:

```
{
    "body": null,
    "status": "NOT_FOUND",
    "statusCode": 404,
    "error": {
        "userMessage": {
            "en": "No user found",
            "fr": "Pas d'utilisateur trouvé",
            "errorCode": 10
        }
    }
}
```

Till there everything is working fine, the only issue is that I can return only as status code **200 OK**

I actually want to **return different status code** according to the event that happened so that in the front-end it can be handle easily as an exception without having to write multiple if..else conditions

Example: Actually in the json that I attached the status code is 404 NOT FOUND but when making the request in postman I receive a 200 OK

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it using a controllerAdvice. This is a class annotated with `@ControllerAdvice` where you define methods for every exception type you want to manage and the result of that function is the response of the api, I mean an httpstatus along with the bosy you want.

In addition to this solution you can use others like using `@ExceptionHandler` in error handler methods inside the controller class. But I think the cleanest way is using a ControllerAdvice.

Anyway, here you can find examples of all the ways you can manage exceptions in spring rest APIs

https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring

Answer (score 0):

HttpStatus codes are returned as part of your Response Object. You might need to do something like this ->

`ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body();`

See the **open source project** - *response-builder* that is a wrapper to construct custom api responses and exception handling -> https://github.com/AccessGateLabs/response-builder

Answer (score 0):

if you use sprint 5 you can try:

```
throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "Foo Not Found", exc);
```

in your controller.